# Use division in Libre Office calc if statement

Tags: if-statement, libreoffice-calc

I've got a Problem in Libre Calc. First i need to compare a couple cells and display them if they contain a letter. This works easy using an IF-Statement and the Search function.

From these i need to check if i got the String more then two times and if yes use a division based an more cells assigned to them.

The function i tried is:

`=IF(R5=R6, SUM(I2/I5), "")`
`=IF(R5=R6, I2/I5, "")`

But both just reply a TRUE, but not the devision. Replacing `SUM(x/x)` by `'x'` displays x.
R5 and R6 are defined as:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("E",B5)),B5,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("D",B5)),B5,""))`
`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("E",B6)),B6,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("D",B6)),B6,""))`

Answer (score 1):

Found the error, Libre Calc always changed the formation of the single cell to boolean, after it was formated.